# Выборка данных по каждому дню за определенный период mysql

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть данные в таблице

```
visit_id    visit_date  hosts   views   
1   2016-08-16  12  45
2   2016-08-01  10  95
3   2016-08-04  24  56
4   2016-08-17  45  134
```

Нужно составить запрос данные по каждому дню за период (например последний месяц). Если нет данных за день то должна быть дата и 0.

Смотрел что нужно процедуру делать и создавать временную таблицу. Пока сам не осилил.

Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: `group by month(visit_date)` `group by date(visit_date)` временную таблицу делать нинада, достаточно left join с подзапросом.

Comment: ну если я сделаю груп то у меня выдаст 4 даты.. а мне нужно каждый день за месяц.. тоесть 30 строк.. даже на те даты которых нет в записях

Comment: могли бы полный запрос написать? а то так мне не сильно понятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не обязательно создавать хранимую процедуру. Однако, скорее всего вам потребуется дополнительная таблица-донор, которая даст вам источник дней за последний интервал. Ниже приводится такая таблица `last_days` в которой находится 30 записей от 0 до 29, которые можно использовать для формирования списка дат за последний месяц. Таблица оформлена как временная, но это не обязательно, можно использовать и постоянную.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE last_days (
  day INT
);
INSERT INTO last_days
VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10),
       (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19), (20),
       (21), (22), (23), (24), (25), (26), (27), (28), (29);
```

Сформировать даты можно при помощи следующего запроса

```
SELECT
  DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL l.day DAY) AS day
FROM
  last_days AS l;
```

Пусть ваша статистика находится в таблице `visists` со следующей структурой

```
CREATE TABLE visits (
  visit_id INT,
  visit_date DATE,
  hosts INT,
  views INT
);

INSERT INTO visits
VALUES
(1, '2016-08-16', 12, 45),
(2, '2016-08-01', 10, 95),
(3, '2016-08-04', 24, 56),
(4, '2016-08-17', 45, 134);
```

Тогда результирующий запрос, извлекающий статистику за последний месяц и группирующий ее по дням, может выглядеть следующим образом

```
SELECT
  DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL l.day DAY) AS day,
  COALESCE(SUM(v.hosts), 0) AS hosts,
  COALESCE(SUM(v.views), 0) AS views
FROM
  last_days AS l
LEFT JOIN
  visits AS v
ON
  DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL l.day DAY) = v.visit_date
GROUP BY
  DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL l.day DAY);
+------------+-------+-------+
| day        | hosts | views |
+------------+-------+-------+
| 2016-07-19 |     0 |     0 |
...
| 2016-08-01 |    10 |    95 |
| 2016-08-02 |     0 |     0 |
| 2016-08-03 |     0 |     0 |
| 2016-08-04 |    24 |    56 |
| 2016-08-05 |     0 |     0 |
| 2016-08-06 |     0 |     0 |
| 2016-08-07 |     0 |     0 |
| 2016-08-08 |     0 |     0 |
| 2016-08-09 |     0 |     0 |
| 2016-08-10 |     0 |     0 |
| 2016-08-11 |     0 |     0 |
| 2016-08-12 |     0 |     0 |
| 2016-08-13 |     0 |     0 |
| 2016-08-14 |     0 |     0 |
| 2016-08-15 |     0 |     0 |
| 2016-08-16 |    12 |    45 |
| 2016-08-17 |    45 |   134 |
+------------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: ну получается судя по решению что создать цикл в пхп будет примерно так же занимать обьем кода. Может тогда стоит мне применить цикл в пхп для создания?

Comment: @Durrasell, да, как вариант, можно решить через цикл в клиентском языке.